# How to improve query performance that inserts data into multiple tables that combines it

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, database-administration

So in my first table I am retrieving only  ID's. 
Then creating and populating multiple table variable and filtering it by :

```
where exists(select * from @ID d where d.ID = @TableData.ID)
```

so structure looks like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------
    declare @DateFrom datetime
            @DateTo datetime 
        --table that contain IDs only
              declare @ID table (ID int) 
              insert into @ID 
                select ID 
                from Table
                where dates between @DateFrom and @DateTo 

        --table with data
        declare @TableData
              select 
                case...
                case...
                case...
                case...
            from Table1
                    join Table1
                    join Table1
                    join Table1
            where exists(select * from @ID d where d.ID = @TableData.ID) --filtering only match IDs from @ID table

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is any way to improve performance somehow?

I tried to create #TempTable instead but still, no improvements.

I thought maybe there is a way  to create index on table variables or temp tables?

Comment: Did you compare it to the same query without the temp table? You can of course put the query you are currently using for the temp table inside the exists clause. I would expect that to be faster in most cases, assuming indexes are in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create table variables with a primary key but you cannot use non-clustered indexes.

If you need to use indexes on temporary tables you should use #tempTables instead. You can then create indexes on those. When working with large data sets the # performs better than the @.